Find $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\log_2\frac{4x-1}{2x+1}$

Find $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\log_2\frac{4x-1}{2x+1}$.

I have solved this problem and my answer is equal to $1$.
This is how I solved it:
$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\log_2\frac{4x-1}{2x+1} = \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\log_{2}\frac{4 - 1/x}{2 + 1/x} = \log_{2}\left(\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{4 - 1/x}{2 + 1/x}\right)$
And from here I found that the limit is $2$ thus the $\log_{2}{2}=1$
I just wonder if I've done it correctly.
Any help is highly appreciated.

The answer is indeed 1, to convince your friends look at the graph of the log.

Hint: Call the limit $L$ and look at $2^L.$ The result should be clear.

@AnneBauval, I'm sure about my answer but one of my friends insists "on absolute 1" which I don't understand his argue, he says it is 1 from left !!!

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\log_{2}\frac{4x - 1}{2x + 1} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\log_{2}\frac{4 - 1/x}{2 + 1/x} = \log_{2}\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{4 - 1/x}{2 + 1/x}\right) = \ldots$$

@ÁtilaCorreia, Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

@ÁtilaCorreia, Yes this is exactly what I did.

Please edit your post to remove the unnecessary mention of other people. Instead post your work on the problem.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

In the case of this particular limit, the answer is $1$, not $0$. You can see this visually if you want to jump onto desmos, but this answer can be shown relatively simply with just the maths side of things. The one thing we can note is the logarithms are continuous, so we can deal with it after the limit. $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\log_2\left(\frac{4x-1}{2x+1}\right)\right)=\log_2\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{4x-1}{2x+1}\right)\right)$$
This inner limit is now way easier to solve. As you can see, it is an $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ situation, so L'Hospitals rule applies. The inner limit evaluates to $2$, and being careful not to forget the logarithm we started with, $\log_2(2)=1$. Thus, the original limit is $1$.

Next time, better wait for the asker to improve and clarify their post before answering
